# How to bind a UITableView to a List<string> using MvvmCross in Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, list, uitableview, binding, mvvmcross

I am working on an application that is Xamarin Native using MvvmCross. I have spent the afternoon looking for an example of how to bind a list of strings to a table view in iOS but every example is binding to a List of Models and not string. I know this can be done in android...

```
  <Mvx.MvxListView android:id="@+id/lvErrors"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_below="@id/lblCaption"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Errors" />
```

where "Errors" is a List of strings. However trying a similar approach in iOS fails to load data.

```
 var set = this.CreateBindingSet<ViolationDetailsView, ViolationDetailsViewModel>();

 var source = new MvxStandardTableViewSource(ErrorsTableView, "TitleText Errors;");

 ErrorsTableView.Source = source;

 set.Bind(source).To(vm => vm.Errors);

 set.Apply();
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to find an example of this?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25601160/mvxspinner-not-binding). "If you want to bind to the whole string object then use a . period for whole object binding."

So...

```
var source = new MvxStandardTableViewSource(ErrorsTableView, "TitleText Errors;");
```

became...

```
var source = new MvxStandardTableViewSource(ErrorsTableView, "TitleText .;");
```

I knew it was something simple.